# Installing php 5.2 ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I want to install php 5.2.x on my server.  I can't find any way to do this. I removed php from the server. My server is running ubuntu.

I tried to follow this one without success.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/262368/is-there-any-repository-for-installing-php-5-2-x-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: Why would you want to install PHP 5.2? It's very old and shouldn't be newly installed. Install PHP 5.6 or directly the latest stable version PHP 7.

Comment: Im using a script that dont work whit the newer php version.

Comment: And your solution to that problem is to install an older version *instead* of fixing the script to work with newer versions?

Comment: "ive tried to follow this one whitout an success" — What went wrong? How are we supposed to give you an answer any different from that one?

Comment: PHP 5.2 reached [end of life](http://php.net/eol.php) half a decade ago. It hasn't had any security fixes since then. Don't use it.

Comment: I'm sure the person asking is aware that 5.2 is outdated.  Sometimes the value of the site you are moving is low, and it is going to be a lot of work to fix the code, so you just want to run the old code as-is and put a web application firewall in front of it and be done.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:txwikinger/php5.2
sudo apt-get update
```

then you should be able to install php5.2 with apt-get install but that's really old stuff now that PHP 7 has been released !

if that's not possible add these two lines to /etc/apt/sources.list add do a sudo apt-get update

Comment: you can also install add-apt-repository by doing: *sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties*

Comment: that worked but ive not succesed whit ap-get install for php. this is the one i typed: sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-mcrypt is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-mcrypt' has no installation candidate

Comment: have you done an apt-get update ? what gives you dpkg-query -S php5 ? (should print all packages containing php5 in their names)

Comment: dont know if it have anything to say but this is what i get hwne i do the apt-get update. 
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.
N: Is the package apt-transport-https installed?

Comment: just do sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https

Comment: and perhaps you have to prior remove the standard php5 : apt-get autoremove php5 php5-common before adding the ppa i suggested, updating and installing again ...

Comment: Okay, when i runned the sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt now it worked but it installed same version that i had before :S

Comment: did you remove the previous version as suggested above ?

Comment: should i do that after running apt-get update and before installing php5?

Comment: yes first remove standard packages  apt-get autoremove php5 php5-common ... and then try installing new ones

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101532/discussion-between-patric-nois-and-gerard-rozsavolgyi).