# Install PHP5.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: php, ubuntu, installation, php-5.2

For some obscure reason, I have to install php5.2 on my VM (Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS) , I'm looking for a PPA, or a way to do it.

How do I Install **PHP5.2** on **Ubuntu** 18.04.1 LTS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:txwikinger/php5.2
sudo apt-get update
```

- [Installing php 5.2 ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34977636/installing-php-5-2-ubuntu)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/597462/how-to-install-php-5-2-x-on-ubuntu-14-04
- https://serverfault.com/questions/778520/how-to-install-an-older-version-of-php-5-2-17-in-linux
- http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/general/php.html
- http://oleksiy.pro/2013/03/29/installing-php-5-2-17-on-ubuntu-aws/